# How to use jquery in Reactjs tag

Tags: reactjs

render() {
    return (

## LargeData

To represent large amounts of data in the browser, a large

```
      <DataGrid

        height={this.state.height}
        style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}
        columns={this.state.columns}
        data={this.state.data}
        options={this.state.options}
      />

      <Divider />

      <Button
        type="primary"
        onClick={() => this.changeConfig('setHeight', 300)}
      >
        height : 300
      </Button>

      <Button
        type="primary"
        onClick={() => this.changeConfig('setHeight', 400)}
      >
        height : 400
      </Button>

      <Button
        type="primary"
        onClick={() => this.changeConfig('setHeight', 500)}
      >
        height : 500
      </Button>
    </Segment>
  </Wrapper>
);
```

I want to use the J-Query property inside that DataGrid tag.
The jquery property is $('.child').resizable({handles: 'se'});
And DataGrid tag is a spread sheet in this project.

Comment: do you really need jquery? and what's do your `DataGrid`?
(btw you should avoid binding your methods in render `onClick={() => this.changeConfig('setHeight', 300)}`)

Comment: Beacuase I want to use this function. ($('.child').resizable({handles: 'se'}))

Comment: DataGrid tag means the spread sheet itself and has low, color and mouse event functions.

Comment: my question is more about the component you are using, what is its API? I mean what props can he take, I am pretty sure it should expose some prop to handle what you want to do. I guess that the finality isn't to call `($('.child').resizable({handles: 'se'}))`

Comment: for example http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/ReactDataGrid exposes a `resizable` prop

Comment: http://axui-datagrid.jsdev.kr
this is a link and I want that spreadsheet to be resized.